# Rails 3 - How to change the parameter :id in resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, nested-routes

In `routes.rb`,

`resources :projects`

gives the following routes

```
/projects/
/projects/:id
```

While using nested resources like

```
resources :projects do
  resources :photos
end
```

it gives the following routes

```
/projects/
/projects/:id
/projects/:project_id/photos
/projects/:project_id/photos/:id
```

This gives me the problem because I have to write controller specific before_filter choosing between `params[:id]` and `params[:project_id]` for doing `Project.find(params[:project_id] || param[:id])`

Is there any way to change the routes to have `:project_id` itself for all routes?

```
/projects/
**/projects/:project_id**
/projects/:project_id/photos
/projects/:project_id/photos/:id
```

Comment: This shouldn't be a problem because your `Project.find params[:id]` will be in your `ProjectsController` and your `Project.find params[:project_id]` will be in your `PhotosController`. If you have something truly unique, you can use http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions and `get :photos, on: :member` which will make `/projects/:id/photos` and use `:id` on all `/projects/` path instead of `:project_id`.

Comment: You could try this trick: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32664225/2131983

Answer (score 2):

Another way is define method, that find current project by :project_id, in ApplicationController

```
def current_project
  @current_project ||= Project.find params[:project_id]
end
```

And redefine this method in ProjectController

```
def current_project
  @current_project ||= Project.find params[:id]
end
```

Then, you can use `current_project` in filters for all your controllers

Answer (score 1):

Name of resource's id param can't be changed

But you can redefine it as non-restful path *before* resourses

```
get "projects/:project_id" => "projects#show"
# etc. for all other 3 methods
```

Comment: So I have to manually rewrite all the routes eh? If thats the only solution, I am worried this will not be DRY.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is Shallow Nesting: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources

Look down to **2.7.2 Shallow Nesting**