# Overriding params in nested routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, actiondispatch

I want to have consistency in naming convention of my routes. Default param is `:id` for any resource. However if one nests another resource in it, param of parent resource changes to `:parent_id`. 
My routing looks like:

```
resources :users do
  resources :projects do
    resources :issues
  end
end
```

For user model it would generate url like `:id`, for project url will be `:user_id/:id` and for issues url will be `:user_id/:project_id/:id`. I tried to overload the default param following [this](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#overriding-named-route-parameters)

```
resources :users, param: :user_id do
  resources :projects, param: :project_id do
    resources :issues, param: :issue_id
  end
end
```

It generates url like: `:user_user_id/:project_project_id/:issue_id`. Since I am overriding it I would want that that default appending of parent resource is off. I want my routes to look like `:user_id/:project_id/:issue_id` and I want it to be consistent for all the models. ie project should be mapped to `:user_id/:project_id`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is how i did it... not sure if there's a better way but it should do the trick...

```
resources :users, param: :user_id

resources :users, only: [] do
  resources :projects, param: :project_id
end

resources :users, only: [] do
  resources :projects, only: [] do
    resources :issues, param: :issue_id
 end
end
```

Answer (score 10):

try `member`:

```
resources :users, param: :user_id do
  member do
    resources :projects, param: :project_id do
      member do
        resources :issues, param: :issue_id
      end
    end
  end
end
```

this code will generate the following paths:

```
      issues GET    /users/:user_id/projects/:project_id/issues(.:format)                issues#index
             POST   /users/:user_id/projects/:project_id/issues(.:format)                issues#create
   new_issue GET    /users/:user_id/projects/:project_id/issues/new(.:format)            issues#new
  edit_issue GET    /users/:user_id/projects/:project_id/issues/:issue_id/edit(.:format) issues#edit
       issue GET    /users/:user_id/projects/:project_id/issues/:issue_id(.:format)      issues#show
             PATCH  /users/:user_id/projects/:project_id/issues/:issue_id(.:format)      issues#update
             PUT    /users/:user_id/projects/:project_id/issues/:issue_id(.:format)      issues#update
             DELETE /users/:user_id/projects/:project_id/issues/:issue_id(.:format)      issues#destroy
    projects GET    /users/:user_id/projects(.:format)                                   projects#index
             POST   /users/:user_id/projects(.:format)                                   projects#create
 new_project GET    /users/:user_id/projects/new(.:format)                               projects#new
edit_project GET    /users/:user_id/projects/:project_id/edit(.:format)                  projects#edit
     project GET    /users/:user_id/projects/:project_id(.:format)                       projects#show
             PATCH  /users/:user_id/projects/:project_id(.:format)                       projects#update
             PUT    /users/:user_id/projects/:project_id(.:format)                       projects#update
             DELETE /users/:user_id/projects/:project_id(.:format)                       projects#destroy
       users GET    /users(.:format)                                                     users#index
             POST   /users(.:format)                                                     users#create
    new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)                                                 users#new
   edit_user GET    /users/:user_id/edit(.:format)                                       users#edit
        user GET    /users/:user_id(.:format)                                            users#show
             PATCH  /users/:user_id(.:format)                                            users#update
             PUT    /users/:user_id(.:format)                                            users#update
             DELETE /users/:user_id(.:format)                                            users#destroy
```

However, **note** that the helpers are not the same as in the accepted answer.

You could use 'as' option to avoid that. More agile solution with as is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41323489/2405850

Comment: you could additionally wrap the resource in `scope(as: :project)` to correct url_helpers. This solution is superior to the accepted as it allows changing the param key to anything, even if it does not include the parent resource name

Answer (score -1):

Try these routes in routes.rb

```
  resources :users, :key => :user_id do
    resources :projects, :key => :project_id do
      resources :issues, :key => :issue_id
    end
  end
```

Comment: Sorry Haider, but it only adds a key to parameters lists: `Parameters: {"key"=>:project_id, "user_id"=>"addie", "id"=>"new_project"}`

Comment: @sonalkr132 you want to convert ` /customers/:customer_id/projects/:project_id/issues` to ` /:user_user_id/:project_project_id/:issue_id` ????

Comment: No! I want it other way round. ie `:user_user_id/:project_project_id/:issue_id` to `:user_id/:project_id/:issue_id`. Overriding the param generates the former .

Comment: @sonalkr132 currently what you have define in routes.rb will produce routes something like `/users/:user_id/projects/:project_id/issues/:id` not like what you are saying `:user_user_id/:project_project_id/:issue_id`

Comment: I know. I want it to look like `users/:user_id/projects/:project_id/issues/:issue_id` and I want the same name of param for all cases. ie `users/:user_id/projects/:project_id` and `user/:user_id`. I tried to achieve it by overriding the param which didn't work.